# Como configurar o TIMEOUT do mysqli no PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho alguns servidores que tenho que testar se possuo conexão.

Alguns desses servidores estão com o acesso bloqueado para a minha maquina para testar, então vão dar a mensagem  `Can't connect to MySQL server on`.

Porém, quando tentam entrar nesses servidores que estão bloqueado, eles ficam muito tempo tentando conectar, então tentei configurar um Timeout seguindo este [link](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-connect.php).

Todavia não está funcionando, fiz o código da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_init();
if (!$link) {
    die('mysqli_init failed');
}

if (!mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');
}

if (!mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10)) {
    die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');
}

include("ConectCTOM.php");

$SELECT_SERVERS = "SELECT * FROM status_db";

$EXECUTE_SERVERS = mysqli_query($conexao, $SELECT_SERVERS);


?>


<br><br>

<?php
$i = 1;
while ($LINE_SERVERS = mysqli_fetch_array($EXECUTE_SERVERS)) {

    $id = $LINE_SERVERS['id'];
    $ips = $LINE_SERVERS['ip'];
    $usuario = $LINE_SERVERS['user'];
    $senha = $LINE_SERVERS['key'];

if (!$conecta = mysqli_real_connect($link, $ips, $usuario, $senha, 'bdcma')){
    echo ('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if($conecta){
    $resultado = "Conectado ".$i;
} else {
    $resultado = "Falhou ".$i;
}

echo '<a>'.$resultado.'</a><br>';

$i++;


}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT é uma configuração muito dinâmica, ela depende do SO que ta usando, da versão do PHP, se pe theadsafe ou não, e várias outras coisas. Por exemplo ela não funciona bem no Windows devido a implementação do TCP/IP. Para o Linux tem que ativar outros modulos e fazer configurações, e mesmo assim só começa a contar depois do handshake (na maioria das vezes nem chega lá), enfim é um parâmetro bem complicado que nunca funcionou bem. Uma possível solução, seria é fazer tudo via API, crie um arquivo .php que funcione como API e retorne um status Ok caso esteja funcionando, coloca o timeout do script para tipo 15 segundos e pronto. Se consegui fazer a chamada e retornar um Ok, tudo certo, se demorar mais de 15 segundos, vai retornar erro de timeout.